# Redirect if a user has not written a post

Tags: redirect

I'd like to redirect two different types of users depending on their role and only if they haven't submitted any post on the site (wether they are pending or published doesn't matter). I am pretty sure I'm supposed to use count_user_posts() but I'm not really sure how to code this :

If a current user role is "A123", and current user has no post in the "B123" custom type, then redirect to 'https://wordpress.org'

Can anyone help me code this properly?
Thank you.

Comment: At which point do you want to redirect and on which page? Are you trying to redirect the actually author or visitors? What have you tried already?

Comment: I want to redirect automatically any user who hasn't created a post to force them to create a post first and then allow them after its creation give them the ability to visit the site. So the function should be affecting only those users who have a specific role and no post created.